# o(h) properties within a poisson processes

Tags: poisson-process

I have this as part of a theorem for the sum of two poisson processes being itself a poisson process. I don't particularly understand why the fourth line equals the last line of the theorem. I believe there should be a λµh^2 in the last line but believe this has been swallowed into the o(h) part of the last line. Why is it the case that this term can disappear please? Thanks

```
Let Zt = Xt + Yt

P[Zt+h − Zt = 0] = P[Xt+h − Xt = 0, Yt+h − Yt = 0]
= P[Xt+h − Xt = 0]P[Yt+h − Yt = 0]
= (1 − λh + o(h))(1 − µh + o(h))
= 1 − (λ + µ)h + o(h), as h ↓ 0
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $o<h<1$ then $h^2<h$.